# Modal not opening in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make modals pop up with info about certain places on a map. Here is the code:

```
<area href="#modal_starthere" data-toggle="modal" title="Start Here" shape="poly" coords="431, 785, 500, 785, 501, 839, 432, 838" />
```

And then later:

```
<div id="modal_starthere" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4>Start Tour Here</h4>
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" style="overflow: auto; height: 425px;">
                <p> <!-- FUTURE CONTENT --></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works great in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE (10) the background goes grey but the modal does not display. Any ideas? I wonder if maybe data-toggle isn't supported in IE.

Comment: can you show a demo, such as on jsfiddle or a link to your own page?

Comment: Note that this bug also can kick into play on Edge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IE does not support the "fade" class for modals, by taking out fade i lost the animation, but the modal displays in all 3 browsers now. I found the answer here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3672

Comment: I tryed it out and if you add data-target="modal_starthere" and it works for me in your area

Comment: Then why does the bootstrap example on their page work with fade in IE?
*edit*: removing the fade doesn't do a thing either. -1

Answer (score 14):

@scalen121 's answer worked for me (the `fade` animation causes it to break).  However, I had a problem with the suggested code fixes..

If you want to remove the `fade` animation just for IE (it doesn't seem to work even on IE11) but leave it for other browsers, then you can add the snippet:

```
$(function () {
    var isIE = window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window;
    if (isIE) {
        $('.modal').removeClass('fade');
    }
});
```

Note that the above IE check is not the same as doing the old: `$.browser.msie`, which returns `undefined` on IE11 (tested with jQuery 1.8.3 and 1.7.2).

Comment: Note that this won't work for Edge. OP didn't mention Edge, and it probably wasn't even available at time of writing, but this note is for future people.

Answer (score 4):

IE so sad. But you can add tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

on after `<html>` tag. It's will work.
And you should include only bootstrap.min.js. It's enough.

Comment: I had to tweak this to run in IE9 mode before it worked; `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

Answer (score 2):

I was also having same problem today. And after removing the fade class didn't work for me even. Thus, I further inspected and found an issue there. The bootstrap isn't able to add `element.style{display:block;padding-right:12px;}` (here element means .modal) in IE. And after adding the following css worked fine:

```
.modal-open .modal {
  display: block;
}
```

Note: I didn't need to remove the `fade` class. And the animation is also working fine.

Comment: BTW, I'm not going to debug the library. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without modifying initial bootstrap layout and code:

```
var $modalWrapper = $('#modalWrapper');
$modalWrapper.on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $modalWrapper.toggleClass('in', true);
});
$modalWrapper.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal-backdrop.fade').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include transition.js file instead of removing the fade class. 
This works fine for me with fade effect in IE10