# Twitter bootstrap modal backdrop not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I've got a modal that i include via jQuery such as:

```
var vCheckModal = 
    "<div id='myModal' class='custom-modal modal hide fade'>" 
        + "<div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button></div>"
        + "<div class='modal-body'><p>Please Upgrade</p></div>"
        + "<div class='modal-footer'><button class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div>"
    + "</div>";
```

It then fires upon a browser check:

```
if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer"){ //If browser is IE
        if (BrowserDetect.version < 10){ //purely for testing
            console.log("less than 10");
            $('body').append(vCheckModal);
            $('#myModal').modal({
                backdrop: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                show: true
            })
        }
    }
```

Works fine when I've changed the modal to appear in Firefox and chrome. But in IE 8,9,10 i see not greyed out background. Yet if i visit the twitter bootstrap demo site, i can see the modal's greyed background fine. Although i think this is initialized differently. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening?

Boostrap v: 2.3.2

Currently using [this detection script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Comment: Could you specify the version of IE and Bootstrap? Also what browser detection tool do you use?

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Comment: @Mat-visual I guess this could be the problem "DOC-TYPE".  So add this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Thanks, this was already in my head :(

Comment: @Mat-visual Oh, it didn't worked?  Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: No prob, i'll make one now

Comment: Maybe your code has a line "console.log("less than 10");"? IE doesn't have console object as default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modal not opening in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329980/modal-not-opening-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making a jsFiddle, i traced the problem to the bootstrap CSS file i was using. I am not sure how but it was missing some CSS. I changed to the correct version, and it's now working fine in IE.