# Getting Stack Overflow in Internet Explorer when using class model

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

In IE, this div tag:

```
<div id="assignSurfaceContentModal" class="modal hide">
```

Throws an error in the console:

```
Stack Overflow error line 12
```

When shown with this line of code:

```
$('#assignSurfaceContentModal').modal('show');
```

I cannot figure out why.   It works in chrome just fine.   When I remove the class attribute, it works fine in IE also, but I want that functionality.   It seems like IE does not like something in bootstrap.   I would prefer not to update the bootstrap version right now, but thinking I may have to, to see if it fixes my problem.

Using IE 11.0.9600.17239

Using bootstrap (v2.2.2) and fuelux ui controls and jquery

Thoughts on how to fix or troubleshoot this?

Comment: Your Bootstrap is way outdated. Bootstrap v2.3.2 is the last+latest of the v2 line. The very latest version of Bootstrap is v3.2.0, but it is not backwards-compatible with v2.

Comment: This appears to have been answered previously, have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329980/modal-not-opening-in-ie

Comment: Yes.   Notice - I don't have fade in the example above :)