# Bootstrap Modal not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap modal does not seem to be working for in both IE10 and IE11.

Here is my webpage:

http://flevy.com/fiaccabrino-selection-process

You can scroll to the bottom and click the "View Full Testimonial" buttons to test the modal.  Once you click it, the screen grays out, but no modal pops up.

I tried to research this issue and found a solution recommending to remove the `.fade` class, but this did not work for me. You can see this code implemented on the page:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // fix for bootstrap modal in IE9+
    if($.browser.msie) {
        // if($.browser.version > 9)
        $('.modal').removeClass('fade');
    }
});
```

Versions we are using:

Bootstrap CSS: v2.0.0

bootstrap-modal.js: v2.0.4

jQuery: 1.7.1

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Why not just upgrade to bootstrap 3.x and perhaps upgrade jQuery too, for example 1.9.1? I think not `.fade` really solves the problems with IE and bootstrap 2.0, there were simply some bugs.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329980/modal-not-opening-in-ie) and [Modal windows do not display on Win8 RP & IE10 #3672](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3672) might help you

Comment: re: @davidkonrad We tried to upgrade to Bootstrap 3.x previously and everything looked completed different, so it's a redesign effort we wanted to avoid for now.

Comment: re: @JSantosh thanks for the link. I've already checked it out, but the solutions proposed didn't seem to work for us.

Comment: We upgraded bootstrap-transition.js and bootstrap-modal.js to 2.3.2 and it's working now.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the proposed solution of removing the '.fade' class did not worked. In my case the bootstrap.min.js wasn't bundled thus the modal function wasn't recognized. After bundling the file all worked well.