# bootstrap modal giving error in ie

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal, and in all other browsers(Chrome, FF, Opera) it works fine, in IE I get an error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'
```

Why am I getting this error? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329980/modal-not-opening-in-ie), but the answers didn't help.

Comment: which version of I.E. ?

Comment: OK, and what version of JQuery are you using? Also check element id's for duplicates

Comment: jQuery 2.1.3 Visit http://tricksfortheweb.net46.net click on `QSS.js` or `Contact`, modals are supposed to pop up.