# Bootstrap modal not drawing in IE

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-modal

I am having an issue with bootstrap modal popups in IE.
I have a modal popup that will render without any issue in chrome and firefox but not in IE.
Actually, the modal seems to render but does not draw; if I click on the space where the modal should be, part of it will display.
I followed this answer [Modal not opening in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329980/modal-not-opening-in-ie) and removed the 'fade' class but this did not resolve my issue.

There are actually several modals on the page and it is the same issue with all.
An example of one is below:
On click of the order-details-button, an ajax call gets a partial view which is appended to the product-order-history-modal.

```
<input id="order-details-button" type="submit" value="View Details"/>
    <div id="product-order-history-modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content opmodal-content" id="product-order-history-modal">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the jquery that appends the data returned:

```
// populate div with partial view
$("#product-order-history-modal").empty();
$("#product-order-history-modal").append(data);

// send confirmation popup    
orderDetailsButton.attr('data-target', '#product-order-history-modal-container');
orderDetailsButton.attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

// prevent background being clicked when modal is visible
$('#product-order-history-modal-container').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
```

Has anyone come across something similar?
Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it *could be* a paint invalidation issue where the browser simply doesn't think the element is ready to be rendered. Can you stand up a small repro via http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com? Also, which version(s) of IE have you tested?

Comment: add `<div class="modal-dialog">` before `<div class="modal-content opmodal-content" id="product-order-history-modal">` and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

So the issue was the modal was coming from a nested partial view. Once I moved the modal container (code shown above) out to my main view, the modal loaded without any issue.

I had a similar issue in the past but the modal did not render at all.... so assumed the fact that it simply didn't paint in this case was a different issue....
And we all know what we do when we "Assume"!

There's a couple of hours I'll never get back but a valuable lesson learned. Thanks for the advice @Sampson and @Shehary