# Bootstrap Modal dialog not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap modal dialog to show processing... message while working on long operation in the background.
link for reference [processing dialog](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/comment-page-1).

It works absolutely fine with the Chrome browser but not working on IE.

```html
$(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            myApp.showPleaseWait();

            //Long operation includes multiple ajax calls.  

            myApp.hidePleaseWait()
        });
    });

var myApp;
myApp = myApp || (function () {
    return {
        showPleaseWait: function() {
             $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal();
        },
        hidePleaseWait: function () {
             $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
        },
    };
})();

<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload"/>
   <div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1>Processing...</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no error in browser console.

If I remove the dialog hide from the button click event, it works fine and dialog shown in IE as well but I want to hide the processing dialog after completion of long operation.

```html
$(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            myApp.showPleaseWait();

            //Long operation includes multiple ajax calls.  

            //myApp.hidePleaseWait() .... COMMENTED DIALOG HIDE...
        });
    });
```

Comment: which version of IE did you choose?

Comment: there is similar question here, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349057/1677272

Comment: its not working for me.